# Asp.Net Ajax Select Sql Query

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webmethod

Hello everyone I want to do ajax select query with parameters. I get select query but I want to do if writen on textbox doesnt have, get message "dont have this query".

**Ajax Code..**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ekle").click(function () {
                $('#ajaxloading').show();
                $("#data").html("");

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Default.aspx/ekle",
                        data: "{'id':'" + txtemail.value + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            $('#ajaxloading').hide();
                            $("#data").html(msg.d);

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        if (txtemail.value == "") {
                            alert('Boş alan bırakmayın..');
                            $('#ajaxloading').hide();
                        }
                        else {
                            alert('Talep esnasında sorun oluştu. Yeniden deneyin');
                            $('#ajaxloading').hide();
                        }


                    }

                });

            });
        });
    </script>
```

**Web Method Code**

```
Web Method Kodlarım



[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string ekle(int id)
    {

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("GonderiNo");
        dt.Columns.Add("Tarih");
        dt.Columns.Add("GonderenAdSoyad");
        dt.Columns.Add("AliciAdSoyad");
        dt.Columns.Add("Adres");
        dt.Columns.Add("Durum");

        using (KargoTakipEntities kargo = new KargoTakipEntities())
        {
            var kargotakip = from v in kargo.KargoTakipSorgu where v.GonderiNo== id select v;

            int i = 0;
            foreach (var k in kargotakip)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
                dt.Rows[i]["ID"] = k.ID;
                dt.Rows[i]["GonderiNo"] = k.GonderiNo;
                dt.Rows[i]["Tarih"] = k.Tarih;
                dt.Rows[i]["GonderenAdSoyad"] = k.GonderenAdSoyad;
                dt.Rows[i]["AliciAdSoyad"] = k.AliciAdSoyad;
                dt.Rows[i]["Adres"] = k.Adres;
                dt.Rows[i]["Durum"] = k.Durum;

                i++;
            }


            GridView g = new GridView();
            g.ShowHeader = false;
            g.BorderWidth = 2; 
            g.CellPadding = 15; 
            g.CellSpacing = 15;

            g.GridLines = GridLines.Both;

            g.DataSource = dt;
            g.DataBind();

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter ht = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            g.RenderControl(ht);
            return sw.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to check textbox is blank or not? Please explain more, not cleared.

Comment: Textbox is blank or not I did. textbox entered data is wrong . I get error "this entered data no data".

Comment: On which event you are getting this error?

Comment: My code is up. I am using ajax and web method. I dont have error. I want to getting error entered textbox is data. Can you look my code you understand.

Comment: What you mean by " I want to getting error entered textbox is data. "

Comment: if the data entered into the TextBox want to inflict error does not match the data in the database.

Comment: Hello did you understand  me?

Comment: Can anyone help me?? Please help me..

Comment: Hi. Sorry for delay. Please provide me teamviewer and your skype details.

Comment: my skype = heymanist